# Application to help with setting the price in GTM

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I noticed that the default price for selling some crafting-related items seems to be much lower than the "market price". Since it's hard to tell what the actual market price is based on what's currently in the market, I'd like to have an application where I would record my sales and use that information to set the price.

Is some application like that available? Either specifically for SWTOR or one that could be easily used with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no functionality to add mods to The Old Republic.

About your best bet for managing prices on the GTN is going to be a copy of Microsoft Excel, a second monitor, and a whole lot of painstaking manual data entry.

Comment: I am aware there are no mods, but I was hoping there would be something smarter than Excel.

Comment: my friend is using a custom quiken thing that I in no way understand, but hopefully I can get him to write an answer to this.

Comment: I doubt even that is useful in the long run. It's still early so prices fluctuate wildly, i.e. there are no 'established' prices for anything.  I just do a search for what I want to sell and put my item 1 credit less than the cheapest I see :)

Comment: @svick Nothing is smarter than Excel. Except someone else using Excel right. :P